# Printing main window in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I need to be able to save the main window of a pyqt app in a PS or similar file format so that I can send it to a printer. I would just make a built in screen shot function but my main window exceeds the size of my screen. Anyone know of a way to capture the window in it's entirety or is there a prebuilt class that could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QPixmap has the static method [grabWidget](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qpixmap.html#grabWidget).

Pointing this method at your window will give you a pixmap that you can save to a file or use for printing.

If calling from inside your main window class:

```
sshot = QPixmap.grabWidget(self)
sshot.save('sshot.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

QPixmap.grabWiget has been deprecated. We can instead use QWidget.grab() function instead to capture window. However, it only captures the currently visible parts of the screen which can be a problem when you have a window with a scroll area. So the only method/hack that worked for me was to use ScrollArea's page step functionality paired with widget grab.

```
# Get total pages in window
page_count = self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().maximum() / self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().pageStep()


image_list = []
# iterate through each page step 
for i in range(int(round(page_count)) + 1):
    step = self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().pageStep() * i
    self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().setValue(step)
    # capture and save each image 
    self.scrollArea.grab().save(f"page - {i}.jpg", quality=100)
    # convert all images to Pillow Image() to later convert to pdf 
    image_list.append(Image.open(f"report_page - {i}.jpg"))

# save as pdf file
pdf_file_name = f'pdf_file.pdf'

image_list[0].save(pdf_file_name, "PDF", resolution=100.0, save_all=True, append_images=image_list[1:])

# delete images if not neccessary 
for i in range(len(image_list)):
   os.unlink(f"page - {i}.jpg")
```

P.s. Please let me know if there a more elegant solution to this problem